# SAP Crystal Decisions integration does not work on Linux

Tags: java, linux, crystal-reports

We are building a web API that calls the SAP Crystal Decisions Library, to generate PDF reports. It works when running on our Windows 10 developer PCs, but when we deploy it inside a Linux Docker image, there is an exception related to libfreetype6 font library. If the library is uninstalled from our Linux image, it complains the library is not installed. If we install the library, either manually with apt-get or by using a docker image that already has it installed we get the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.fontembedding.opentype.tables.OS2Table.(SourceFile:108) ~[CrystalReportsRuntime.jar!/:12.2.226.3772]```

SAP Support claims there is no direct dependency on this library, so I am wondering where to start in troubleshooting this issue. I cannot locate it on my Windows machine either. How can I confirm whether it's included in the JDK? I have tried Java 10 and Java 11 JREs and JDKs, the error is the same.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in Linux, you can check the versions [on this page](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html):

[image]

And [will not be supported ever](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/End+of+SAP+Crystal+Presentation+Design), unlikely SAP will develop any new features except patches for the out of sale software.

Answer (score 0):

In our tests, this issue does not occur using JDK 8 on Linux.  It begins happening when using JDK 11 and higher.  In JDK 11, Oracle removed the T2K font rasterizer, no longer ships any fonts and relies entirely on fonts installed on the operating system.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html